# Gathering various information from different tabs into a summary tab

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to figure out how to make a macro (button) that gathers specific information from all my tabs in my worksheet and pastes it into my summary tab. Here is an example:

WorkSheet #1 = "Cric"

```
Cell A1 = 1 Cell A2 = 2 Cell A3 = 3
```

WorkSheet #2 = "Crac"

```
Cell A1 = 4 Cell A2 = 5 Cell A3 = 6
```

WorkSheet #3 = "Croc"

```
Cell A1 = 7 Cell A2 = 8 Cell A3 = 9
```

This is what I want to do: in my summary cell I would like to make a button that when I click on it automatically gathers the information in cell A1/A2/A3 in all the tabs beside summary and then copies it in my summary worksheet to A1;B1;C1...Ax;Bx;Cx. Also please take note that the tab name beside summary might change since I'll use this Excel sheet on various projects.

I've had projects in the past with 30ish worksheets so I definitely need this macro to save time!!

WorkSheet #4 = "Summary"

```
Cell A1 = 'Cric'!A1 ; Cell B1 = 'Cric'!A2 ; Cell C1 = 'Cric'!A3
Cell A2 = 'Crac'!A1 ; Cell B2 = 'Crac'!A2 ; Cell C2 = 'Crac'!A3
Cell A3 = 'Croc'!A1 ; Cell A2 = 'Croc'!A2 ; Cell A3 = 'Croc'!A3
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is there anything you have tried so far that we can help you with? We are here to help programmers and programming enthusiasts. Showing some effort will go a long way.

Comment: I've been trying a few things but none of them worked =/. I am not really good in VBA so i was trying to various code and modify it but it's not working.

Comment: Greetings Pnuts,

Summary is basicaly my tab that i gather all the information from various site (tabs) and from there i calculate the COST of the project.

Comment: So beside some "IF" , "sumif" , vlookup there isn't any logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague, so I don't know that this will really help.  But as stated, you're trying to take the values in the first COLUMN of each worksheet, and move them into ROWS into your summary sheet.  So Cric A1 to 3 becomes Summary A to C1.  That's called transposing.  I'm going to assume that the Summary sheet is blank to start, and that the order of the rows will be the order of the tabs.

```
sub MakeSummary()
Dim WkSht as Worksheet, R as Integer

R=1
For Each WkSht in Worksheets
  If WkSht.Name<>"Summary" Then
    WkSht.Range("A1:A3").Copy
    Worksheet("Summary").cells(R,1).PasteSpecial transpose:=true
    R=R+1
  End If
Next WkSht

End Sub
```

Haven't tested it, but that should work.  If you don't want just the first three rows but the entire A Column moved to your summary sheet:

```
sub MakeSummary()
Dim WkSht as Worksheet, R as Integer

R=1
For Each WkSht in Worksheets
  If WkSht.Name<>"Summary" Then
    WkSht.UsedRange.Columns(1).Copy
    Worksheet("Summary").cells(R,1).PasteSpecial transpose:=true
    R=R+1
  End If
Next WkSht

End Sub
```

EDIT:
You added some details that the data you're interested in is in S8 to U8 on the sheets.  I hate to say this, but if you can't see how to adjust the code above to address this, I'm not sure that VBA macros are a good idea for you as you'll be always wanting to adjust.  Anyway, your data is actually already in a row (R8 to U8 are 5 horizontal cells in row 8).  So you don't need to transpose anything.  Here's what you do:

```
sub MakeSummary()
Dim WkSht as Worksheet, R as Integer

R=1
For Each WkSht in Worksheets
  If WkSht.Name<>"Summary" Then
    WkSht.Range("R8:U8").Copy
    Worksheet("Summary").cells(R,1).Paste
    R=R+1
  End If
Next WkSht

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi hpf, Sorry if my question is vague. I will try to rephrase it:
I'm an account manager and sometime I need to do some estimate for customers that own many buildings. Each building have its own worksheet with their own value , that being said in every of those worksheet I summarized the important information into 5 different cells (right now those cells are Q8;R8;S8;T8;U8). 

Knowing that every separated worksheet has the information summarized into those 5 cells, I would like to automatically “transpose” the value on my “summary worksheet”.

Comment: In my "summary worksheet" each building needs to have its own row (if the project has 15 building well ill have 15 rows, if there is only 5 then 5 it is). Also please take note that I’m trying to do a template that would work for any project no matter how many worksheet I have or what is the name of the worksheet. I hope this help, Thanks, Jonathan A.